# Using tqdm progress bar on Heroku server

Tags: python, heroku, tqdm

I am using the following code to produce a [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) progress bar. I see the progress bar when I run the code locally, but not when I run it on Heroku.

```py
from tqdm import tqdm

for item in tqdm(items, total=len(items)):
    # do something with the item
```

I was wondering:

- why this is the case
- if there are settings that could enable the progress bar logging on the server
- if there are any memory-related downsides to leaving the progress bar code there, even if it is not visible on the server

Basically if anyone has any context to share about using tqdm on the server, I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Did you have any luck finding a solution for this?